Unexpected error while signing transaction if fee payer is set
basically i got api endpoint that creates few transaction like:
Wallet A -> Wallet B and
Wallet B -> Wallet A
basically im just creating transaction on backend, serializing with ```
{
verifySignatures: false,
requireAllSignatures: false
}
returning it back to client script, deserializing with `Transaction.from(...)`

however when it comes to `window.solana.signAllTransactions`, i get `Unexpected error` in console.

What's interesting is that, it's only happening if feePayer is set to third wallet. When wallet A is fee payer everything works fine. What could be the issue?

i use @solana/web3.js.

More code:

```js
const from = new PublicKey("...")
const to = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(process.env.HANDLER_PRIVATE_KEY!))
export const feePayer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(process.env.FEE_PAYER_PRIVATE_KEY!))

const transactionsFrom = makeTransactions(from, to.publicKey, feePayer.publicKey)
const transactionsTo = makeTransactions(to.publicKey, from, feePayer.publicKey)

for (const transaction of transactions) {
        const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({
            verifySignatures: false,  // only fee payer signature is required for now
            requireAllSignatures: false
        });

        serializedTransactions.push(bs58.encode(serializedTransaction))
    }

return res.json({
    transactions: serializedTransactions
})

const signedTransactions: Transaction[] = await walletProvider.signAllTransactions(transactions)

The only thing i can think of is that wallet A signature is not needed in the second tx, however how can make phantom ignore transaction that are not meant to be signed by wallet A?

You need to sign the transaction with feePayer if it's paying for the transaction. In this code, it's only be declared as the fee payer, but never actually signing the transaction.
For each transaction, be sure to do something like:
transaction.sign(feePayer);

And make sure there's a valid blockhash on the transaction before the signing.

in my case unexpected error was caused because the wallet signing (phantom) was not required as a signer

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
